# How to install Redis in windows

Tags: windows, redis

How to install Redis in windows as a installer without installing wsl (Ubuntu)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ePdm4AyL0s

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases

Comment: The above installer works fine... Thanks to the contributor...

Comment: This is a very old version of Redis, version 3.0. Redis is up to version 7.0 now. Furthermore, it is not an official release as there are no official releases for Redis that run natively on Windows. I would expect this to work unpredictably with modern libraries and frameworks.

Your best bet is to use either WSL or Docker. Or use a cloud provider.